# Slice dataframe based on list of dates with different frequencies

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, dataframe, slice

I try to slice a dataframe by rows based on dates of interest.  `df_data` has an  index  based on `datetime` with the format `YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss`.
It contains data from 2012-01-01 until 2018-06-30 on a 1 minute frequency. The other `dataframe` is containing a column with the dates of interest but is frequenced daily with format `YYYY-MM-DD`.
 I transformed this `dataframe` into a list called `dates_interest`.

I tried `df_final = df_data[df_data.index.isin(dates_interest)]` to slice the dataframe according to my needs, but `df_final` returns a dataframe with length of 0.
I guess it has something to do with the different frequencies/formats.

Comment: Since it’s a DatetimeIndex you can slice it with just the strings. [partial string indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#partial-string-indexing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sure there is a more elegant solution, but I suspect your dates of interest are being interpreted as midnight (date and minute). If so, you'll want to pull out the days from that df_data, then try to your slicing again.

```
# get a column of the days from your df_data
df_data['just_day'] = df_data.index.dt.date

# append the individual slices from each day into your df_final
df_final =pd.DataFrame()
for date_of_interest in dates_interest:
    df_final.append(df_data.loc[df_data['just_day']==date_of_interest]
```